# showing image from resources folder with only using JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, jboss

I have images of products. I wanted to render these images with  html tag in jsp. I put images in src/main/resources directory in intellij idea. I am creating war file and deploying it on jboss server. I have tried a lot of paths to specify src attribute of img tag, but it can't find image. I have seen a solution where people create another servlet and pass it local path to the image to render, but I want to do it with just JSP.
So the question is, where should I save images, or which path should I write in img src attribute to render the image, without creating additional servlet?

Answer (score 0):

We're using JSTL tags in JSP to render the images from resources folder
Import statement : `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`
Usage :  `<c:url value='/images/softy.jpg'/>`
For us Images are in Resources/images folder.

Comment: and where is the resources folder? I am using maven archetype. Is it in webapp? so the images folder path is src/main/webapp/resources/images? or something else?

Comment: Yes its an webapp and location of images is 'src/main/webapp/resources/images'